# Match complete object using objectContaining instance in jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to do a complete match using `objectContaining` instance in jest.

Below is the example object I am trying to match:

```js
 const queryCommandInput = {
          KeyConditionExpression: '---keyConditionExpression---',
          ProjectionExpression: '---projectionExpression----',
          FilterExpression: '---filterExpression----',
          ExpressionAttributeValues: { //[1] - Unable to match from here
            'value1': { S: 'example1' },
            'value2': { S: 'example2' },
            'value3': { N: 12345 },
          },
          TableName: 'tableName'
        }

const queryCommand = new QueryCommand(queryCommandInput);
//[2]
 expect(DynamoDBClient.prototype.send).toBeCalledWith(expect.objectContaining({input: expect.objectContaining(queryCommandInput) }))
```

[1] - Unable to do a multilevel match without using multi objectContaining ([2])

I could have another object containing, and then another objectContaining after that. But not able to find any other better way to automatically iterate and match all the key/values

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution. I am sure this will be helpful for a lot of developers out there.

Destructuring and overriding the behaviour for the properties which we know a match would fail, works!!

In this scenario, `queryCommand` is an instance of a class `QueryCommand`. The below statement would fail because even though the inputs are the same, the instances are different.

```js
expect(DynamoDBClient.prototype.send).toBeCalledWith(queryCommand) //the queryCommand is a different instance from the instance being sent to the send method of DynamoDBClient conrtuctor, hence it fails.
```

That is why I was using the objectContaining class, but that only matches one level. If the object is nested, multiple nested `objectContaining` must be constructed. The best way is to not use an `objectContaining` constructor, but to match the instances itself and restructure it so that we only check the types of the properties which we know will change, and complete/deep check the properties that we want.

```js
expect(DynamoDBClient.prototype.send).toBeCalledWith({ ...queryCommand, middlewareStack: expect.any(Object) })
```